# Using Flask-restful to make a GET function but got the following error : [requests.exceptions.SSLError] [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]

Tags: python-3.x, flask, openssl, flask-restful, restful-url

I am currently developing a function using Flask-restful to call a GET function of get a QR code from another site. But got the following error :

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='testing-site', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /testing/getQR?clientID={clientID}&responseType={response-type}&source=PC_Browser&redirectURI={redirect-url} (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)')))

My code are as follow:

```
qr_request_body_web = {'clientID' : clientID, 'responseType' : 'code', 'source' : 'PC_Browser', 'redirectURI' : server_domain + authcallback_path}

def getQR():
response = requests.get('testing-site' + api_auth_getqr_path, params = qr_request_body_web, allow_redirects=True)
return redirect(response.url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(port=80, debug=True)
```

I can call the GET function on Postman & Chrome, is there any configuration I need to set for python to get it work? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the "http://" is the same in the browser and the requests URL parameter. If not make it the one that you see in the browser. Let me know if that helps you or not.

Comment: the answer can add more value if you can provide code that contains the correction that you are suggesting.